# Django Rest framework: Allowing developer to access te browseable api without a token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We are using Django Rest Framework in our web projects, and it's great. We also use headers based authentication with token etc.. That creates a situation where our developers can't easily browse the browesable api without getting a token, pasting it, etc.

Is there a way around this? disable token security for the browersable api and allow some kind of basic http user/password auth? maybe IP protection? Any other Ideas how to solve this problem? I'll love to hear feedback from other DRF users.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this with `TokenAuthentication` but it should be the right way to go (of course you need to make it a mixin and reuse it):

```
class MyAwesomeView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    # some more attributes

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.get_format_suffix(**kwargs) == 'api':
            self.authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)

        super(MyAwesomeView, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it and report back